# When I add dropout to tensorflow NN, the test accuracy gets worse

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Hi I am trying to add dropout to my tensorflow MNIST data set classifier. Before using dropout, I get a test accuracy of around 95%. When I add dropout, it goes to around 10% (the normal odds of guessing) even though the cost is being reduced. when I change both dropout values to 1, it does work. but when i change the first dropout value to less than 1, it stops learning. what am i doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 300
n_nodes_hl3 = 100
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784]) #placeholder as input
y = tf.placeholder('float') #placeholder as output
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
pkeep = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

max_learning_rate = 0.003
min_learning_rate = 0.0001
decay_speed = 2000.0 # 0.003-0.0001-2000=>0.9826 done in 5000 iterations

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_classes])),}



    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1) #uses relu function as activation function
    l1d = tf.nn.dropout(l1, pkeep)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1d,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
    l2d = tf.nn.dropout(l2, pkeep)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2d,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
    l3d = tf.nn.dropout(l3, pkeep)

    output = tf.matmul(l3d,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']
    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( 
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 9
    with tf.Session() as sess: #the with statement has something to do with code cleanup when done
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for i in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size) #the epochx is the pics and the epochy is the labels
                # learning rate decay
                learning_rate = min_learning_rate + (max_learning_rate - min_learning_rate) * math.exp(-i/decay_speed)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y, lr: learning_rate, pkeep: .5})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
            print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels, pkeep: 1.0}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

the output is:

```
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Epoch 1 completed out of 9 loss: 1047962.8098
Accuracy: 0.1043
Epoch 2 completed out of 9 loss: 12696.1747944
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 3 completed out of 9 loss: 4314.31121588
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 4 completed out of 9 loss: 2532.65784574
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 5 completed out of 9 loss: 2025.4943831
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 6 completed out of 9 loss: 1732.2871151
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 7 completed out of 9 loss: 1656.68535948
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 8 completed out of 9 loss: 1512.10817194
Accuracy: 0.1135
Epoch 9 completed out of 9 loss: 1463.4490006
Accuracy: 0.1135
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me the problem is the fact that it is a shallow network and using dropout for very first layer, means that even very basic features which form a basis for learning more complex features deeper in the network, don't propagate to the deeper layers. A reason why dropout works in deep CNN's for instance is that, a very low level representation of input has already been developed by a lot of convolution layers, so then, when you apply dropout to fully connected layers, you try to ensure none of the lower level features is given excessive importance, in short there is no over-fitting.

So, in short I would recommend not having a dropout in the initial two layers, and the accuracy should be better.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found out that when you model something a little more complex you have to choose your initialization parameters more carefully. I would suggest you to initialize the variables like this:

```
tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1))
```